# How can I manage ids of entities in Linq2SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Such a task: we have 2 tables in our L2S Entity classes. It needs to manage with current fields of current tables by numbering em somehow.

Exact question is How can I point to the exact field of exact table without using entity relation names? Such as TmpLinqTable[2] instead of TmpLinqTable.TableField.

Moreover if it can be managed by ids of the entity, not the table.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are attempting?  Are you saving new records to the db?  If so after it is saved the object that you did the Add() on will automatically have it's new ID.  Again, not sure that I understand the question without an example of what you are attempting.

Comment: Are you using linq to entities or linq to sql? They are distinct different technologies. Please edit/retag your question with what you are actually using.

Comment: Linq2SQL. 
example is simple: the point is to log all the actions with db without db triggers, all actions must be atomic simple. 1 insert to db is logged with a simple info of time, user, action and so on, and moreover logging names of fields, tables, new values... and also want to write logger that isn't linked with the exact db... thats why i need to manage tables, fields without using its entity names... just ids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my understanding of what you are trying to do is to log changes that happen to your entites. Is that correct? You might want to look into the GetModifedMembers method on the Table class. Here's an interesting link...

http://geekswithblogs.net/steveclements/archive/2008/04/15/linq-to-sql-property-changed--changing-logging.aspx